# C# WPF Get dynamically created image child ID

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 methods. One creates dynamically an image, the other one removes it.Everything works fine in the first method. In the second method it also works if I specify the position where to remove the image ( RemoveAt() ). I know that image is created with the ID of 13. Is there any way to get the Id of the var m dynamically ? Thank you.

---

```
private static void CreateImage ( double imageWidth, double imageHeight, double xPos, double yPos, string imageSource, string imageName)
    {
        m = new Image();

        mainWindow main = Application.Current.Windows[0] as mainWindow;
        main.mainGrid.Children.Add(m);
        m.Height = imageHeight; //Image height
        m.Width = imageWidth;//Image width
        //Width conversion to X
        double halfWidth = main.Width;
        double w = ( -halfWidth + xPos + imageWidth ) ;
        Convert.ToInt32 ( Math.Round(w) );
        //Height conversion to Y
        double halfHeight = main.Height;
        halfHeight = -halfHeight;
        double h = ( halfHeight + yPos + imageHeight ) ;
        Convert.ToInt32 ( Math.Round(h) );
        m.Margin = new Thickness(w, h, 0, 0);//left, top, right, bottom
        m.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Resources\" + imageSource + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
        m.Name = imageName;
    }
    private static void DestroyImage()
    {
        mainWindow main = Application.Current.Windows[0] as mainWindow;
        main.mainGrid.Children.RemoveAt(m.);

    }
```

---

Comment: Do not create UI elements in code behind. Use an ItemsControl instead, that has its ItemsSource property bound to a collection of an item class that represents the image. Adding and removing elements would be done on the source collection. The ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl defines the visual appearance, i.e. contains the Image element. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: can I add multiple bitmaps to the same element and use it in multiple instances in the same time? Is that possible? I would imagine if I create a UID that adds 1 every time the method is called, maybe I can hook to that.Actually I shouldn't say multiple bitmaps but rather one bitmap every time the method is called but I would have a different UID each time

Comment: Sure you can. Read the Data Templating Overview article. Then search the web or StackOverflow for e.g. ItemsControl and Image.